# Google Analytics, internal link analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'll use StackOverflow as an example.

A user can reach a question/answer page from

1. outside of stackoverflow
2. from another page of stackoverflow

   - from a search result
   - from a link in other posts (link in another question or answer)
   - from `Similar Questions` section
   - from a user profile page

I'd like to know how those internal links are used.
Main question is `What are the percentages of each type of links which led users to the Q/A page in stackoverflow`
I want to know the answer for the Q/A pages as a whole not for each individual Q/A page.

Is this implementable using GA and if so, I'd like to hear a general guide so I can dig in.

Is there a term for this kind of analysis? (internal link analysis? Knowning a term helps me to google further..)

---

Edit

I found one way to do this using sitesearch.
http://cutroni.com/blog/2010/03/30/tracking-internal-campaigns-with-google-analytics/

It's from 2010, and not sure its still the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, I've implemented it using Google tag manager.

I defined event `navigateToQnA`.
And fired the event with different `event action` for different type of clicks I care about.

Maybe bit laborious than the sitesearch method I linked in the question.
But cleaner in a sense that you don't pollute url parameters to collect the data.

Comment: Err you just had to add Id paramas to the <A> tags to make them unique, there was no need to decorate the urls with new params.

Anyhow GTM + link click trigger + UA events tag sounds fine for in page activity tracking.

Comment: what do you mean? adding params to <A> tags isn't the same as adding params to url ?

Comment: no:  <a id='15' href="https://example.com/page/path?utm_source=google" ... params are used to define things like source medium

Comment: Oh.. I see. using the linkid.js I guess. I guess it's doable. I tend to use same template (html) from multiple codes, and using javascript to mark a click was easier. (Of course I could use javascript to add an id to <A>, then rely on linkid.js.) Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

To be able to tell different links from the same page e.g. you will need to   setup enhanced link attribution by requiring the plugin via this command

```
ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
```

the plugin also requires decorating each link that reffers to the same destination (the question) a unique id. you can also chose to decorate a container element such as a div which holds link or its parent (up to 5 levels)

there are a number of ways to get at this data.

One way is a under reporting look at Behavior>Behavior Flow. The view crates a  sunkey diagram. which you can narrow down using a custom segment + creating a content grouping. The advantage of the Behavior flow is that it is visual - but it is difficult to customize.

Another approach you could take is to locate the question in the Behavior > Site Content>All pages and the set the secondary dimension to "Previous Page Path". You can use the advanced filter to select a specific question, and to limit the previous pages to page paths matching the pattern for each type of page you discussed. 
To view the attribution for different links you need to select the In-Page Analytics tab.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Previous page path won't differentiate links within an answer post from links from related section on the right. (stackoverflow example)

Comment: Ok I've updated the answer with details for differentiating links using the [Enhanced Link Attribution](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558867?hl=en) and the [In-Page analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558811?hl=en) tab.